# Set correct and incorrect buttons' templates simultaneously

Tags: android, view

I am having a method, handling the correct/incorrect answers entered in a quiz game:

```
public void answerButtonClickHandler(View v)
{
    Answer answer = myAnswers.get(v.getId());
    if (answer != null)
    {
        myQuestionsAnswered++;
        if (answer.isCorrect())
        {
            myCorrectlyAnswered++;
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answer_button_correct);

        }   
        else
        {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answer_button_incorrect);
            }
        }
```

What it is doing so far is to check if the answer is correct or not (this part works fine) and sets a corresponding template. What I'd want to add as functionality is when the wrong answer is marked, the correct one to be marked as well. I was trying to keep the state of the vies (v) in a new View variable, in both of the states, but have not done the trick so far. Thanks you!

Comment: You could do a for loop to search the view that has `answer.isCorrect()` and mark it.

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler, may you give me  a hand with the code? So far I set it either to only correct, or to only wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Post the code where you create the views and i can try to help you

Comment: I changed the approach a little bit, showing the correct answer under the question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want, please post the solution that you found and mark it as accepted